# Unable to change font color in django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I wrote a code in django and I want the html page font color to be red.

The following is the html file.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/css/base.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% if blogs %}
            {% for blog in blogs %}
                <ul>
                    <li>{{ blog }}</li> 
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <p>No Blogs are available.</p>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: HTML file]

The following is the css file

```
li {
    color: red;
}
```

[image: CSS file]

The following is the output I am getting-
[image: Output]

I am new to django and some help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to hard refresh the webpage by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + R` to see if it is using a cached, older version of the CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to adjust a few settings in the settings file. I can't say for sure as I can't see your file. I think you have a static file in your project file where you store static files; ***..\project_example\static\css\base.css*** then you will need to define the location and url of the static files. settings file should be like this or similar specifications:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
```

In html, you can reach css with an arrangement like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
```